# Error when using inline Assembly with gcc to enable switch into protected mode from real mode

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline, inline-assembly

when coding a script with C and using inline assembly I get the following error:
I compile with my usual settings:

```
gcc -m32 -ffreestanding -c kernel.c -o kc.o
```

And i get this error from gcc:

```
junk `8h:PModeMain' after expression
```

The code that I used is a code of osdev.org adapted to the gcc rules, is the following:

```
void k_enter_protected_mode()
{
    __asm__ volatile ("cli;"          
        "lgdt (gdtr);"  
        "mov %eax, cr0;" 
        "or %al, 1;"    
        "mov cr0, %eax;" 
        "jmp 08h:PModeMain;"
        "PModeMain:");
}
```

The code is intended to swap form real mode to protected mode, thanks in advance!

Comment: GCC inline assembly uses AT&T syntax. Your jump uses Intel syntax. See e.g. [this comparison page](http://www.imada.sdu.dk/Courses/DM18/Litteratur/IntelnATT.htm) for a few details. Most notable `08h` should be `$0x08`.

Comment: I corrected that changing "JMP" for "jmp" and the error stays appearing, so Iḿ not sure if that was the problem, but thanks anyway @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Your inline assembly seems to be Intel. Are you sure you aren't also compiling with `-masm=intel` ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude changed too the "08h" but now at compile appear this 2 errors: kernel.c:118: Error: junk `:PModeMain' after expression
kernel.c:118: Error: operand type mismatch for `jmp'

Comment: is `0x8` a segment number? Shouldn't it be in a segment register?

Comment: Try with `-masm=intel` added to your _GCC_ command line options and then modify the JMP to be `JMP 0x8,PModeMain;`

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya : It is a far jmp using immediate operands. So in this case it is correct to use a segment number and an offset.

Comment: There is a big issue with your code. You copied the code from http://wiki.osdev.org/Protected_Mode but failed to notice that it is intel syntax. The order of operands is reversed. For instance `or %al, 1;` makes no sense in At&T syntax.

Comment: I'm also going to point out that it is a very bad idea to use variable names (GCC docs very strongly discourage it) inside an assembly block like this. You should be using extended inline assembly and passing `gdtr` as an input operand. If you are new to inline assembly I suggest dropping it and putting assembly code in a separate object and using GCC to link to it.

Comment: @MichaelPetch my assembler (llvm assembler) is not ready to compile `jmp 0x8:label` in any way. Can this instruction be used only in real mode?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya : Far jumps apply to 32-bit code as well

Comment: Well, thanks all, with the last comment of @AjayBrahmakshatriya I solved the problem, all was fault of the JMP line, now I have another error related to the gdtr that MichaelPetch sayed at linking with another assembly script, but that's other problem for other question since is a totally different problem. Thanks all.